J. J. Thomson's Famous Violinist argument: libertarian or begging the question?
I don't understand why Judith Jarvis Thomson's The Famous Violinist thought experiment is so influential. Her whole framework appears to be strongly libertarian, using a negative conception of rights. And yeah, from a libertarian perspective, it's probably easy to argue for the permissibility of abortion.
But it's the celebrated argument of the liberal left: bodily autonomy.
Yes, you aren't legally required to give your blood to the violin player. But why should you? You're not responsible for his predicament in any way.
A more fitting example would be cases where you harmed someone's health in a life-threatening manner, but you could save him with a body part of yours. But compatible donors are not so easy to find, and so the issue realistically never arises.
Admittedly, “You destroyed his lungs, so you have to give him yours now — it's only fair!” sounds ghoulish, and so triggers our strong “civilized Western” aversions. Still, I deny that we have well-thought-out opinions on this. It's too far-fetched.
How do we get from those few contested examples to the supposed “right to bodily autonomy”:

The right to decide about other people's use of your body parts or the ressources originating from your body (A)

Where does this come from? Bodily integrity is a right, that I know. But from this, the right to interfere in any non-pathological bodily process (like pregnancy) does not arise. Another right is the freedom from cruel punishment. But it's not like the state deals out impregnation as a punishment.
This “right” (A) is simply too bizarre, too specifically constructed for this case in an ad-hoc manner. It only sounds like begging the question.
However, if Judith Jarvis Thomson meant:

The right to be the sovereign and exclusive controller of one's own body and life (B)

… I'll grant her the soundness of her argument. Yet, this is a libertarian view, the famed self-ownership.
My country forced me to crawl through the mud and play-fight against “country red”. More relevantly, it will also force parents to care and provide for their born children. I don't see how her arguments should not apply to legalizing child neglect, except for some special pleading that it's different when it's about the body.
So a violation of the strong libertarian right is commonplace. And anyone except libertarians has no problem with that. In other words, the argument is successful when granting strong libertarian self-ownership, but this simply proves too much.
Question: I've seen both interpretation, and wonder what's the right one? I barely can't believe she meant it like (A) but that's how it is often defended against objections. But if she understood it like (B) was J. J. Thomson libertarian? I didn't find any mention of that.

Saying that parents (both) having to provide for their kids instead of leaving this charge to the community and women (only) having to put their health in jeopardy when ending the pregnancy has no effect on the people around her is hardly special pleading. Those are very different cases.

In the scenario I've read, a group of classical musicians kidnaps the "victim" and forces them to keep the violinist alive, which clearly most people would feel is criminal but still seems to me different enough from pregnancy to make the argument not convincing (except maybe in the case of rape)

For one, Thomson endorses the right to life, which is a positive right, and engages in rights balancing, which is anathema to libertarians. For a detailed compare and contrast, see Block, Thomson on Abortion; a Libertarian Perspective. He does note that the right to one's own body "places her in the highest reaches of libertarian theory", but also leads to inconsistencies in her arguments. "Unhappily, she does not score a libertarian touchdown. But, for a scholar who is not herself a libertarian, she comes mighty close."

I’m voting to close this question because abortion is a "hot topic" leading to contrarian debate undesired on this site. Also it could be much shorter.

Also, abortion rights are a political and emotional matter, in public debate they are not treated as philosophical matters and not decided based on reason alone.

@tkruse I asked a question about an article published in a philosophical journal by a well-known American philosopher. So I certainly asked a philosophical question. Why should we care that the public debate about the same issue is emotional or irrational? I propose to wait if contrarian debate really arises. And then maybe try less harsh tools, like protecting the question instead of voting to close. PS: every philosophical issue, even the most abstract and remote ones, is probably influenced by emotions.

@Conifold I think she only gives some lip service to positive rights and yes, she weighs rights, but there's an implicit switch to a wholly libertarian conception of rights for the central argument. Or put more snidely: where her argumentation is not libertarian, it is confused, inconsistent or suffers from irrelevant digressions; where it is libertarian, she argues clear, sound and convincing. I'm also baffled how such a libertarian-ish piece was historically used to defend a cornerstone of the liberal left, bodily autonomy.

@armand sure providing for kids is different from pregnancy, but the problem is that she argues via analogy. So I can also simply say that her original violin player analogy is a very different case, since it involves kidnapping. My concern is that she simply is not transparent what rights she appeals to! It honestly sometimes feels like strong libertarian negative rights, quote: “if you refuse, you are, like the boy who owns all the chocolates and will give none away, self-centered and callous, indecent in fact, but not unjust.”

@Conifold I entirely agree with your linked article. But it would be interesting if she or someone else defended her article against the charge that it is simply a libertarian argument for evictionism with a confused veneer of “liberal paint”.

The book "Catastrophe Ethics" covers this case. Take a look.

Not specifically about the linked article, but I think one should default to maximally hostile skepticism whenever considering any argument from analogy for something which is easily understood on its own. Analogies can either simplify or distort. If the analogy does not in fact serve to simplify the problem, it either does nothing or it distorts.

Claim A comes straight from John Locke's Second Treatise on Government

Sect. 27. Though the earth, and all inferior creatures, be common to
all men, yet every man has a property in his own person: this nobody
has any right to but himself. The labour of his body, and the work of
his hands, we may say, are properly his. Whatsoever then he removes
out of the state that nature hath provided, and left it in, he hath
mixed his labour with, and joined to it something that is his own, and
thereby makes it his property. [...]
Sect. 28. He
that is nourished by the acorns he picked up under an oak, or the
apples he gathered from the trees in the wood, has certainly
appropriated them to himself. Nobody can deny but the nourishment is
his. I ask then, when did they begin to be his? when he digested? or
when he eat? or when he boiled? or when he brought them home? or when
he picked them up? and it is plain, if the first gathering made them
not his, nothing else could. That labour put a distinction between
them and common: that added something to them more than nature, the
common mother of all, had done; and so they became his private right. [...]

The body is the fundamental property from which all other property rights derive. While there are cases where the state may lay claim to that fundamental property — punishment for crimes, military conscription, etc. — it is generally considered an extreme measure, and a grave risk to Liberal rights in society.
That being said, the difference you're making between claim A and clam B seems doesn't seem to be much of a difference at all. If one is the "sovereign and exclusive controller of one's own body and life", that seems to entail that one can "decide about [how] other [people use] your body parts or the resources originating from your body." If one cannot decide that in every case, then one is clearly not sovereign and exclusive controller of one's body.
The Famous Violinist argument is written to be provocative, and thus leans a bit towards the absurd, but it's easy enough to translate it into pragmatic and commonplace terms. I mean, let's say that we decided to end the problem of homelessness: or better put, the problem of people who cannot or will not support themselves. Common approaches to this problem are:

Public welfare or minimum basic income schemes that take tax dollars to house and feed indigents
Public charity options that allow for voluntary contributions to indigents
Criminalization of indigence so that these people are jailed and then put to involuntary labor in exchange for the jail's food and shelter (and don't fool yourself that this option is odd or unusual)

These all have their disadvantages: (1) extracts money from taxpayers to feed and house unproductive people; (2) entails that a significant number of indigents will die from exposure and malnutrition due to insufficient voluntary donations; (3) not only costs tax payers money (incarceration is not cheap), but in no way actually solves the problem.
Now let's try a fourth option:

Craft a law which makes the person closest to where an indigent settles down is responsible for housing and feeding the indigent.

That would certainly solve the homelessness problem, but it hardly seems fair to whomever gets stuck with the burden. Would any of us want to be responsible for housing and feeding someone because they happened to sit down on the sidewalk in from to our house?
Getting this back to Thompson, this is the point she's reaching for. A fetus is effectively an indigent — a person that cannot support itself, and is entirely dependent — that sat down close to a woman without her even knowing: is she then obliged to take care to it? Now, most women follow approach 2: they are perfectly willing to provide for the fetus as a matter of love and charity. There are some limited and ineffective modes of approach 1, like SNAP programs, welfare benefits, etc, but even such limited and ineffective programs are generally vilified by conservatives. Approach 3 makes no sense in this context, unless we start talking about arresting pregnant women or developing techniques for fetal transplant surgery, both of which sound… disturbing. So without the possibility of abortion, women are stuck on approach 4.
Complain all you like about me comparing a fetus to an indigent; economically that's exactly what it is. And so you see how the argument goes.

We can argue endlessly about whether we have Free Will, but for Responsibility, there is no debate.

Have you even read the article that you cite?

My argument will be found unsatisfactory on two counts by many of those who want to regard abortion as morally permissible. First, while I do argue that abortion is not impermissible, I do not argue that it is always permissible. There may well be cases in which carrying the child to term requires only Minimally Decent Samaritanism of the mother, and this is a standard we must not fall below. I am inclined to think it a merit of my account precisely that it does not give a general yes or a general no. It allows for and supports our sense that, for example, a sick and desperately frightened fourteen-year-old schoolgirl, pregnant due to rape, may of course choose abortion, and that any law which rules this out is an insane law. And it also allows for and supports our sense that in other cases resort to abortion is even positively indecent. It would be indecent in the woman to request an abortion, and indecent in a doctor to perform it, if she is in her seventh month, and wants the abortion just to avoid the nuisance of postponing a trip abroad. The very fact that the arguments I have been drawing attention to treat all cases of abortion, or even all cases of abortion in which the mother's life is not at stake, as morally on a par ought to have made them suspect at the outset. (Literally the start of the 8th section)

But even if you just read the famous part up to the 1st section. Even there she starts arguing for and from a POSITIVE right to life of the fetus and contrasts it not with an absolute negative right of the woman to her body, but with an equally POSITIVE RIGHT of the woman to life. Like by chaining her to the bed or even shortening her life, you're not just "saving" a life and grant the fetus the positive right to life you also REJECT that woman's positive right to life or her life at all. Also as mentioned in the first quote she provides a variety of different scenarios and argues against treating them all the same. Like there's a difference between the violinist requiring help for 9 minutes, nine months, nine years or whether heart transplant that will cost your own life.
She further outlines that giving the example of the good Samaritan who goes out of his way to help while the priest and the levite went right by the injured person.
Where she argues that people should be at least minimally decent samaritans that help a person in need, but that requiring to be good samaritans is a different category of claim.
Sidenote: The often missed point in the Good Samaritan example is that "Samaritans" are (as far as I learned that) not actually a nation of particularly nice people, but at the time were enemies to the Jews. So this example hits even harder when you consider that the priest (moral authority) passed by the injured person, the levite (legal authority) passed by, so all the people who one might have thought had some moral obligation to actually help passed by, while the Samaritan the person from whom no one could have even expected to help, for whom it would have even been "permissible" to experience schadenfreude over the misfortune of that person, that was the guy who actually went out of his way (figuratively and literally) and who took on personal hardship and losses to save that person whom he had no reason to save to begin with.
So even a minimally decent Samaritan would have gone out of his way. Jesus than goes on to ask his followers which of them did the right thing and as his followers argue it's the last one, he asks them go out and do likewise.
End of sidenote.
Where she then goes on to contrast that with the case of Kitty Genovese who was apparently raped and murdered in broad daylight and no one intervened. And where she argued that no law (in the U.S.) even required the 38 people who were apparently present at the crime, but didn't do anything to prevent or mitigate it, to be minimally decent samaritans and do anything about it. While apparently pregnant women are expected to be GOOD SAMARITANS and go out of their way to help.
Which is quite a contrast if you argue from moral principle and Christian values.
So she's explicitly not making the case that "I'm not required to be bothered with the lives and well being of other people... at all." is a good stance to have, she's merely mentioning the hypocrisy that is applied in many of these cases by taking an absolute stance on abortion, which is inconsistent with these principles are applied elsewhere.
Also she uses that violinist example primarily as an example to make the case for abortion in case of rape, as that is more akin to being kidnapped and subjected to help someone with no fault of your own or agency in accepting or rejecting. While she apparently uses a whole lot more arguments in other places (I also just skimmed the thing).
Also last but not least, don't confuse confuse "libertarian" in the sense of a U.S. political philosophy originating from Old Right Conservatism in the 60s with philosophical libertarianism.
Like the concept of "self-ownership", at least to me, sounds more like people are working backwards to defend property by attaching it to the most foundational and existential properties of human existence the own body and the own self, thereby justifying further claims to non essential properties that would otherwise be controversial.
So even outside of claims of self-ownership it's pretty apparent damaging someone's body, imprisoning a person and taking away their positive liberty does grave harm to that person and that beyond any human laws that allow or disallow that, you're actually attacking that person and should expect them to break and/or negatively react to that.
You really don't need any concept of ownership over yourself to express that problem or to express your aptitude, capacity and essential need to have full control over yourself. In fact it's the other way around, expressing these features in terms of property is majorly lacking. While you could destroy, abandon, sell or buy property. The same is hard, immoral or even impossible for the human being. You have to go out of your way and make use of tools to damage and kill yourself, because otherwise your body would literally fight those approaches and might at time make you go blackout before you're able to beat yourself to death. Similarly you cannot abandon or disown yourself. No matter how hard you try you'll always be yourself, maybe with drugs or certain types of insanity or whatnot, but it's really hard if not impossible to stop being yourself without stopping to be. Same for buying and selling, you can sign contracts or whatnot if you so please, but you could never effectively seize ownership of yourself and the other person could never effectively exercise full ownership over you beyond some very superficial layer.
You will always be yourself and that's a kind of ownership that is unlike any other relation that you're having to any other type of property. So actually it doesn't make that much sense to think of yourself as your own property for that matter. UNLESS you just use that as a means to segway into property rights and how government regulations and taxes are similar to cutting off limbs and enslaving you. Which they aren't, but emotionality beats rationality (at least in the short run). So no you can very much make argument in support of a positive right to life as a consequence of the human condition without going down the route of self-ownership and U.S. political libertarianism.

My country forced me to crawl through the mud and play-fight against “country red”. More relevantly, it will also force parents to care and provide for their born children. I don't see how her arguments should not apply to legalizing child neglect, except for some special pleading that it's different when it's about the body.

And from an actual libertarian perspective forcing you to crawl through the mud and play-fight or even actually fight an enemy of theirs is a grave injustice to the individual. So just because real live governments often enough act immoral why would that make it right?
Also in terms of parents she explicitly makes the case between taking up that responsibility and taking aims to prevent it early on. See section 7.
So from what I can see she's not making the case that you think she is, nor is she inconsistent in doing so, it's more like you're arguing with a strawman version of her argument, aren't you?

Well, though other people complained, my question wasn't long enough, it seems, since you completely misunderstood it! Read the first part again: the problem is that the 38 people didn't have ANY relationship with Kitty Genovese. So for random strangers in need, our duties are very minimal indeed. I wholeheartedly agree. But a woman's unborn child is not remotely like this. So there must be a mysterious strong right to bodily autonomy, that overrules all. Like… what?

The whole article is a non-stop series of liberal veneers (with ad-hoc assumptions) tacked onto a libertarian frame, and my question would be overly long if I listed that ALL. Traditionally, women gave birth in their homes. Children weren't taken home from the hospital. So what's actually the rule? If we get into the nitty-gritty details here (e.g., what does caring for the infant — born in the home — for a single day mean?), we could easily end up with rules that a pregnant woman similarly implicitly accepts special responsibility. “Implicitly” is always a very problematic word.

I didn't read all this but it feels like it raises some good points. The book "Catastrophe Ethics" covers it well and thoroughly though.

The problem with the Kitty Genovese argument is that it didn't happen as described by Thomson - that's at least what your Wikipedia article says: "there was 'no evidence for the presence of 38 witnesses, or that witnesses observed the murder, or that witnesses remained inactive'".

@viuser No, actually according Christian morality (and that seems to be a common angle that people take) explicitly (by Jesus himself) makes the point that you should not only help random strangers, but especially ENEMIES. Helping those from whom you're going to be repaid or that you care for is explicitly not enough. Also with regards to "rules" you need to differentiate between regulations that exist because people want them to exist and necessities following from a moral framework. Like a tyrant could mandate people to walk on one leg, but that doesn't really explain the morality in it.

@viuser So in other words: Why is the relation between a woman and an unwanted unborn child any closer than that to a random stranger? You presuppose that this is the case but you make no case for why that actually is the case. Not an expert in biology but from what I know pregnancy hits women with a pretty hard chemical cocktail of hormones that make them want to take care of the child and bond with it, but that is their business not really societies business or something you can or should mandate by law, is it? Like at least Thompson mentions a positive right to life as potential explanation

@viuser Maybe you should appreciate for a second that "liberal" and "libertarian" are quite similar words and that it's absolutely not surprising to find overlapping lingo with respect to 2 ideologies that concern themselves with individual liberty... Even if for libertarians that's largely a veneer to support property rights. Also how does it matter where people are born and what makes you think people always had houses of their own? There's a good chance most babies were born on the spot, if lucky with a blanket or whatnot.

@viuser 4/4 Also you could make the argument for a responsibility of a planned parenthood, where parents agreed to make a child and from that develop a responsibility to care for it. But the violinist is more of a description of rape, so where does the responsibility come from here?

@IgorF. It wouldn't even matter if it never happened at all, as it's merely an example and she might as well have chosen a completely fictional one as she did with the violinist. So hardly a problem, right? Also the original faulty article of the crime is reprinted since 1964 so loads of people probably knew the case, while the debunking happened decades later.

Thomson thinks about conception and pregnancy like Aristotle, not modern science. For Aristotle, only sperm is imbued with the power to create life while women's bodies are passive, inert vessels (like her people seed & carpet example). But the oocyte is a part of the woman's body that actively transforms (after fertilization) into an embryo. What is the political framework that relieves one from all accountability for what one's body does (as long as it isn't an intentional act), e.g. producing viruses?
